# Can javaCV be used with GAE(Google App Engine)?

Tags: google-app-engine, jar, external, javacv

Can i use javaCV with GAE??

Now, i try to import javaCV jar to GAE,GWT project in Eclipse

But it wasn't work...

First, I makes GAE project in Eclipse that was installed GAE plug-in

and add javaCV jar file to /war/WEB-INF/lib

and config jar Build path

so it wasn't confirm error in source

But when i run WebApplication(local)

some errors occur..

like this

```
[ERROR] [jebal] - Line 72: No source code is available for type com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage; did you forget to inherit a required module?

[ERROR] [jebal] - Line 73: No source code is available for type com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame; did you forget to inherit a required module?

[ERROR] [jebal] - Line 119: No source code is available for type com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Now, I guess that GAE can't use with javaCV library or it's wrong method to add jar.

How add external library to GAE proeject?
Can i use javaCV with GAE??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) is a java wrapper around a set of native libraries: opencv, ffmpeg, etc..

There is no way it can be run on GAE.

Comment: No, you can not use native libraries on GAE.