# Can javaCV(based on openCV) be used with GAE(Google App Engine)?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, opencv, javacv

javaCV is wrapper library that based on openCV.

But I want to use it on GAE..

Because I developing image matching sever..

If I capture some image on mobile, send to sever.

And then sever is match send image and own image that locate at database server (server has Java servlet and datastorage).

And last! Server send to result image that most similar image on database.

Cae GAE do this function T_T ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can javaCV be used with GAE(Google App Engine)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938546/can-javacv-be-used-with-gaegoogle-app-engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run native C code on App Engine, and javaCV, just being a wrapper for OpenCV, requires native code to run.